# Multi-value parameter SQL vs Informix

Tags: reporting-services, informix, business-intelligence

I am using SSRS, going against an Informix database. I need to pass a list of mobile numbers through SSRS and retrieve the data from the Informix database. The report runs well when I pass a single mobile number but it doesn't work for a comma-separated list of mobile numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Without code I think that you use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM phone_info
WHERE normalized_phone_nr=123456789;
```

I would change it to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM phone_info
WHERE normalized_phone_nr IN (123456789, 1123456789, ...);
```

or even fill temporary table and then:

```
SELECT * FROM phone_info
WHERE normalized_phone_nr IN
    (SELECT normalized_phone_nr FROM my_temp_table);
```